# Can't call doPost() method of servlet in jsp page

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, jsp, servlets

At beggining. There is a application structure.
I have 3 MySQL tables ( Obiekt, Termin, Rezerwacja). In project i have jsp page (here is code) :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@ page import="test.Obiekt"%>
<%@ page import="test.ListaObiektow"%>
<%@ page import="test.Termin"%>
<%@ page import="test.ListaTerminow"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>menu główne</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">


<meta name="android-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="android-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
<link href="css/ratchet.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/ratchet-theme-android.css" rel="stylesheet">


<script src="js/ratchet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Refresh(idObiekt){
    location.href="pilkaNozna.jsp?idObiekt=" + idObiekt; 
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    <header class="bar bar-nav">
        <a class="icon icon-left-nav pull-left" href="wyszukaj.jsp"></a>
        <h1 class="title">Wybierz obiekt</h1>
    </header>

    <div id="content">
        <div class="tabelawybor">

            <b>Wybierz obiekt:</b>
            <%
                ArrayList<Obiekt> list = new ListaObiektow().getObiekty();
            %>
            <form>
                <select name="obiekt" onChange="Refresh(this.value)">
                    <option value="0" selected>Wybierz Obiekt</option>
                    <%
                    String selectedObiekt = request.getParameter("idObiekt");
                    int counter=0;
                    for (Obiekt obiekt : list) {
                        if(selectedObiekt == null && counter==0)
                        {
                            selectedObiekt = Integer.toString(obiekt.idObiekt);
                        }

                %>
                    <option value="<%=obiekt.idObiekt%>"
                        <%= ((Integer.toString(obiekt.idObiekt)).equals(selectedObiekt))?"selected":""%>><%=obiekt.nazwa%>
                        <%=obiekt.adres%></option>

                    <%
                    }

                %>

                </select>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="tabelawybor">
            <td><b>Wpisz liczbę uczestników:</b><input type="text"
                name="uczest" /></td>
                <% String liczbaUczestnikow = request.getParameter("liczbaUczestnikow"); %>
        </div>

        <div class="tabelawybor">
        <form action="Rezerwacja?action=doPost" method="post">
            <table class="center">

                <tr>
                    <td>Nazwa obiektu:</td>
                    <td>Data:</td>
                    <td>Godzina</br> rozpoczęcia:
                    </td>
                    <td>Godzina</br> zakończenia:
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <%
                ListaTerminow listaterminow = new ListaTerminow(); 
                listaterminow.setId(selectedObiekt);
                ArrayList<Termin> lista =listaterminow.getTerminy();
                String idTermin = request.getParameter("idTermin");
                    for (Termin termin : lista) {
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%=termin.nazwaObiektu%> <%=termin.adresObiektu%></td>
                    <td><%=termin.dzien%></td>
                    <td><%=termin.odKtorej%></td>
                    <td><%=termin.doKtorej%></td>
                    <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary">Zarezerwuj</button>
                        </td>
                </tr>
                <%
                    }
                %>
            </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

In this jsp page i have select form which have List of Obiekt (this list is created in ListaObiektow.java), but it works. I also have table form which contains List of Termin (created in ListaTerminow.java). It works too. But, in this table form there is button to make Rezerwacja.

I made Rezerwuj servlet. Here is code:

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import test.ConnectionClass;
import test.Rezerwacja;
import test.Termin;/**
 * Servlet implementation class Rezerwuj
 */
@WebServlet("/Rezerwacja")
public class Rezerwuj extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Connection conn;
    private int idTermin;
    private int liczbaUczestnikow;
    public Rezerwuj() {
        super();

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        conn = ConnectionClass.Polacz();
        ArrayList<Rezerwacja> rezerwacje = new ArrayList<Rezerwacja>();

        PreparedStatement st = null;

        ResultSet rs = null;
        String sql = "INSERT INTO rezerwacje (liczbaUczestnikow,idTermin) values ('" + liczbaUczestnikow + "','" + idTermin + "')"
         + "UPDATE termin SET termin.czyZajety=true WHERE termin.idTermin = '"+ idTermin +"'";              

        try
        {
            st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            if(liczbaUczestnikow > 0 && liczbaUczestnikow < 20)
            {
                rs = st.executeQuery();

            }

            while(rs.next())
            {
                Rezerwacja rezerwacja = new Rezerwacja();
                rezerwacja.setLiczbaUczestnikow(rs.getInt(1));
                rezerwacja.setIdTermin(rs.getInt(2));
                rezerwacje.add(rezerwacja);
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public void setIdTermin(String id)
    {
        idTermin = Integer.parseInt(id);
    }
    public void setliczbaUczestnikow(String liczba)
    {
        liczbaUczestnikow = Integer.parseInt(liczba);
    }

}
```

When i click on the button, it returns error like this:

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
    test.Rezerwuj.doPost(Rezerwuj.java:63)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

What i want:
I select one of option in select form, then type value (0-20) into text input, then click on button and create a record in MySQL table Rezerwacja. Any suggestions ?

Comment: `<form action="Rezerwacja" method="post">` instead of `  <form action="Rezerwacja?action=doPost" method="post">`

Comment: your are getting `NullPointerException` on your servlet.Fix it. It will work

Comment: What's the line 63 of Rezerwuj.java? From what I understand your code does not set the variable "liczbaUczestnikow" at any point, therefore getting the NPE

Comment: Blah. I have to totally rewrite Rezerwuj servlet. What do i have to do in this servlet to put variables into mysql query, then take this variables from forms in jsp ?

Comment: We can take doubts here, that's what the site is for, not do your work for you ;) Google a little around and you'll find plenty of information on how to, small tip, separate things, first get your data from your form to your servlet.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form action="Rezerwacja?action=doPost" method="post">
```

In this line the action is where you are sending the request, so it should be action="Rezerwacja" and method should be method="POST"

Comment: This is not an answer. Write as comment adives like that

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with `liczbaUczestnikow` after initialization is always `0`. As result `rs` always `null`, therefore exception thrown.

Comment: liczbaUczestnikow = request.getParameter("liczbaUczestnikow") should be enough ?

Comment: Yes it will be enough, if you have this parameter in your request,  just cast `liczbaUczestnikow` to `int`.